# The relation between a model and it's form in Django, and user authentication

Tags: django

I'm migrating something from an old PHP/apache server to Django. I'm a bit stumped with the 'ModelForm'.

As far as I understand, a "Model" is the abstraction for persistent elements in my website/server - specifically this is something stored physically, say in a database, and defines the fields (read columns) in the DB.

I started moving the authentication part of the site, and discovered models, and specifically the User model (I made an empty User inheriting AbstractUser just in case I will ever need to extend things). Now I want to create a simple two field form, to authenticate login.

The form:

1. Username (which is a field of User, by default)
2. Password (Which is not).

Even the 'Username' needs a redefinition in the model form. So my questions:

1. What is the advantage of the model form (over just a form)? - seems like you're redefining fields anyway, and obviously sometimes adding fields on top of the model.
2. Specifically for authentication, I probably need to store my salted hash associated with the user somehow, compare my password using that and retrieve the user object. This is something I find very hard to find in the Django docs - they just have too much written on authentication, and not one full code example. Do I put this in the "validate" method of form, retrieving there an object and storing it in a session or something?

If there is a deeper relation between a model form and the associated model, I would like to know as well.

Comment: password is also  a field of user model

Comment: user model already stores password in hashed form (sha-256). You really don't need to do anything for hashing.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki See, the docs are obfuscated enough I missed that, thanks. If possible, I'd appreciate an answer with code examples.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Also, I'm rendering now - The password field is rendering as a type text input. I know how to change this using 'widgets', but why the heck is that the default?

Comment: because for django it is just a textfield there is nothing like password field. You have to do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple django forms and modelforms have quite differences.

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Article
         fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']
```

The above example illustrates that you don't have to write any form field in here. The model form will itself create a form which is based on the attributes provided in the model ('Article' in this example).

If you create a simple django form then it would be something like:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.CharField(some_attrs)
    ...
```

The django User model provides you everything you need for authentication. When you want to create users just `import django.contrib.auth.models.User` and use create method to create objects. Then when you want to authenticate a user use `authenticate` method.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
def user_login(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    # after authentication login the user or set cookies or modify the session or some other action can be taken
    return HttpResponse("Some response or use render for html page")
```

username and password will be coming from your post request.

If you want to extend default Django user model you can use django user model as `onetoonefield` in your extended model.

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ... # other custom fields
```

Comment: Thanks, so the model forms need specification of field names only, and initializes the fields itself. Two things missing for me: Where do I authenticate? I saw the code you posted in the docs, but I obviously don't want to authenticate on load, but on submit to the form. Since I control the form action, where should I direct the POST request? Do I get the form/model context there?

Comment: See the edit.  Create a url for user_login method and put that in your form action

Comment: Thanks, spot on what I needed.